# Problems compiling ocaml project on debian bulleye: undefined reference to shm_unlink and shm_open

Tags: ocaml, ocamlfind

Trying to compile the ocaml project from

https://gitlab.com/benjgregoire/maskverif/

I (having no clue about ocaml) get, after installing all the missing libraries, the error message

```
+ ocamlfind ocamlopt -rectypes -cclib -lrt -linkpkg -g -thread -package zarith,unix,menhirLib,ocamlgraph -I src src/util.cmx src/expr.cmx src/pexpr.cmx src/poly.cmx src/poly_solve.cmx src/shrcnt.cmx src/state.cmx src/checker.cmx src/ilang_ast.cmx src/ilang_parser.cmx src/ilang_lexer.cmx src/parsetree.cmx src/prog.cmx src/ilang.cmx src/parser.cmx src/lexer.cmx src/main.cmx src/shrcnt_low.o -o src/main.native
/usr/bin/ld: src/shrcnt_low.o: in function `shrcnt_destroy':
/home/myname/work/maskverif/_build/src/shrcnt_low.c:74: undefined reference to `shm_unlink'
/usr/bin/ld: src/shrcnt_low.o: in function `shrcnt_create':
/home/myname/work/maskverif/_build/src/shrcnt_low.c:99: undefined reference to `shm_open'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/myname/work/maskverif/_build/src/shrcnt_low.c:95: undefined reference to `shm_unlink'
```

From what I found on the internet, it looks like the library rt is given to the gcc linker at the wrong position via -lrt, but I have no idea how to fix this, as it is called by some ocaml binary.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same problem was reported in [this issue](https://gitlab.com/benjgregoire/maskverif/-/issues/4).

The maintainer's response was as follows:

> This issue was very tricky to fix.
> You can find the current fix on the SPINI branch.

So, you can try to checkout the [SPINI](https://gitlab.com/benjgregoire/maskverif/-/tree/SPINI) branch and try to build.

---

As far as I understand, the problem is that in the [Makefile](https://gitlab.com/benjgregoire/maskverif/tree/ce1780d60a2e4abe83c7c605ee3e78b2f88c7fdf/Makefile#L22) they can't properly pass the `-lrt` to the linker. In the SPINI branch, they [switched](https://gitlab.com/benjgregoire/maskverif/-/blob/SPINI/Makefile) to using the dune build system and solved this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I have a strange error message about version 2.8 of dune language not being supported, despite having installed 2.7.1, but I hope to figure that out, when I'll have a bit of time for it. Great help!

Answer (score 0):

In meanwhile I was able to compile the SPINI branch as suggested by jubnvz in his/her answer. It did not work using the ocaml/opam/dune packages provided by debian/bulleye, but uninstalling all ocaml-related debian packages and following the installation instructions from the README at https://gitlab.com/benjgregoire/maskverif/tree/SPINI did work fine for me.